# Why are my values in a C++ map class member wiped?

Tags: c++, object, arduino

I have 2 classes: `InuReading` and `InuTask`. Looking like this:

InuReading header:

```
class InuReading{
    public:
        InuReading(String t, String l){
            type = t;
            label = l;
        };
        String type;
        String label;
        std::map<String, String> data;
        void set(String key, float d);
};
```

InuTask header:

```
class InuTask{
    public:
        InuTask(String);
        String type;
        void addTemperatureReading(String sensor, float temperature);
        std::vector<InuReading> readings;
    private:
        InuReading newReading(String t, String l);

};
```

InuReading method:

```
void InuReading::set(String key, float d){
    data[key] = String(d); 
};
```

InuTask methods:

```
InuTask::InuTask(String t){
    type = t;
}

InuReading InuTask::newReading(String t, String l){
    InuReading r(t, l);
    readings.push_back(r);
    return r;
}

void InuTask::addTemperatureReading(String sensor, float temperature){
    InuReading r = newReading("temperature", sensor);
    r.set("d", temperature);
    // Size here after setting "d" to 30.0 is 1, which is proper
    Serial.printf("Size of %s is now: %i \n", r.type.c_str(), r.data.size());
}
```

Main:

```
InuTask task("Log");
task.addTemperatureReading("Temperature", 30);
// This returns 0, all data is missing now?
Serial.println(task.readings[0].data.size());
```

Immediately after data is set on the map, it has 1 element, but once I get the InuReading from the vector its data property is empty. How do I get the data to stick in the map?

Comment: life would be much easier if you adopted a naming convecntion for member variables - ie _readings for the Task member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newReading` returns the `InuReading` by value, which means that `r` in `addTemperatureReading` is a local object and has no relationship whatsoever to the objects stored in the task's `readings` vector.

You probably want `newReading` to return a reference, and change `addTemperatureReading` to use a reference too:

```
void InuTask::addTemperatureReading(String sensor, float temperature){
    InuReading &r = newReading("temperature", sensor);
    r.set("d", temperature);
    // Size here after setting "d" to 30.0 is 1, which is proper
    Serial.printf("Size of %s is now: %i \n", r.type.c_str(), r.data.size());
}
```

Note that this change also requires you to return a reference *into* the `readings` vector from `newReading`:

```
InuReading& InuTask::newReading(String t, String l){
    readings.push_back(InuReading(t, l);
    return readings.back();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a big workaround. Couldn't he just move the `push_back` into `addTemperatureReading` after modifying `r`? Wouldn't it make more sense to be pushing back there too?

Comment: @scohe001 The reason I'm doing push_back in newReading is to hopefully avoid a bunch of copy paste code since addTemperatureReading is just one of many sensor reading functions.

I tried changing newReading to `InuReading& newReading(String t, String l);`, then changed the definition to `InuReading& InuTask::newReading(String t, String l){` and finally did `InuReading &r = newReading("temperature", sensor);`, but then the program crashes when run.

Comment: @scohe001 That would be equivalent to simply removing the `newReading` function altogether (as it would exactly duplicate the reading's ctor then). I wouldn't consider this a workaround. To me, the semantics is sound: "Register a new reading, and allow me to customise it." However, I can see where you're coming from too, and if you were my reviewer, I'd be willing to adapt.

Comment: @Angew ahh fair enough, I suppose OP has his reasons for sticking it in there then. +1 for making it work while doing it OP's way :)

Comment: @user2145184 There was a piece of needed change missing, I've added it.

Comment: One thing has me confused though, why was I unable to create the InuReading object, then push into the vector before returning it? Instead of pushing into vector and then reading from the vector as return value?

Comment: @user2145184 Because local variables go out of scope when the function exits. You can of course still have the local variable `r` in `newReading` if you need it, but you need to return a reference to the object *actually* in the vector.